# Probabilty function of random variable

Tags: probability

2 balls chosen randomaly from a jug.
The jug containts $8$ white balls, $4$ black and $2$ orange.

For each black ball, we earn 2 dollars.

For each white ball, we lose 1 dollar.

And for orange ball, we dont lose and not earn.

What is the probabily function of the random variable X ?

Let X be the amount of dollars we have after we choose the balls.
I know that -

$P(x=4) = \frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{14}{2}}$,

$P(x=2) = \frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{14}{2}}$,

$P(x=1) = \frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{1}}{\binom{14}{2}}$,

$P(x=0) = \frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{14}{2}}$,

$P(x=-1) = \frac{\binom{8}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{14}{2}}$,

$P(x=-2) = \frac{\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{14}{2}}$

My question is,There is some $P(x=r)$ function ?

Comment: Just multiply each of those 6 numbers with a indicator function and add them up.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: The indicator function $\mathbb{1}_{[-2,-2]}$ is 1 when computed in -2, and 0 otherwise. So this should be multiplied by the last number. Similarly for the other 5, and then add up.

Comment: Sorry for this, but still dont understand.
Can you give me an example please ?

Comment: Rad this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: I know what is indicator function.
But, I didnt understand how to use it in this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there can be a "total function" (in the sense that, there can't be a PDF that takes on values for all of its' domain - $Z$.

Because as you have noticed yourself, $P(X = 3)$ is clearly undefined.

Random tidbit - such functions show up in computer science and are called as [partial functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function).